# minlength validator not working in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have create schema in mongoose

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        minLength: 4,
        maxLength: 15
    }
});
```

when I update it with this query

```
user.updateOne(
        { "_id" : body.id },
        { $set: {
            name:body.name,
            phone:body.phone,
            designation:body.designation,
            address:body.address
        } }
    ).then(function (updateDate) {
        var data={message:"success",data:updateDate}
        callback(data)
    }).catch(function (err) {
        var data={message:"error",data:err}
        callback(data);
    });
```

It does not throw any error if I update string with 2 length.
There are few solutions on stackoverflow but these are not working in my case

Comment: try adding mongoose  `let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ });`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, in your schema `minLength` must be `minlength`, and `maxLength` must be `maxlength` with lowercase **l**.

So your schema must be like this:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        trim: true,
        minlength: 4,
        maxlength: 15
    }
});
```

Secondly, you need to add  `{runValidators: true}` option to updateOne.

> Update validators are off by default - you need to specify the
> runValidators option.

So your code must be like this:

```
  user.updateOne(
    { _id: body.id },
    {
      $set: {
        name: body.name,
        phone: body.phone,
        designation: body.designation,
        address: body.address
      }
    },
    { runValidators: true }
  )
    .then(function(updateDate) {
      var data = { message: "success", data: updateDate };
      callback(data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      var data = { message: "error", data: err };
      callback(data);
    });
```

Comment: I'm saving a new user to the database, where should I call that `{ runValidators: true }` ? I didn't have any mistake in writing the `minlength`, all is right but still does not work and registers users with lower than 6 digits password which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You simple open mongodb Compass and then go to Validation option and change validation level to strict mode.